# How to link graphviz with VIsual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, graphviz

Someone please tell me How to link graphviz( or call its code) in C++ (VIsual Studio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Graphviz has a documentation [Using Graphviz as a library](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf). Is that what are you searching for?

Just in case, [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a2-using-libraries-with-visual-studio-2005-express/) described how to use libraries in Visual C++.